# jQuery get certain value of data-value

Tags: jquery

so I have this html

```
<li data-value="http://127.0.0.1/home/opencart/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=46&amp;tracking=55c0fff37d4e0"><a href="#">Sony VAIO</a></li>
```

I can get the data-value property like this:

```
var f=$('.col-sm-10 ul li').attr('data-value');
```

but I'd like to get 'product_id' from the url. How can I achieve that?

https://jsfiddle.net/mhnomvck/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to parse product id from url. Try this:

```
var f=$('.col-sm-10 ul li').attr('data-value');
var productId = f.match(/product_id=([^&]+)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a regex using the jQuery [data function](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and [wildcard ("attribute contains") selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```js
var f=$('.col-sm-10 ul li[data-value*="product_id"]').data('value'); 
$('div').text(f);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-value="http://127.0.0.1/home/opencart/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=46&amp;tracking=55c0fff37d4e0"><a href="#">Sony VAIO</a></li>
<div></div>
```